# X Error: BadMatch when adding widescreen resolution to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, display, resolution, xrandr, nvidia-settings

**Problem:**

I upgraded my monitor from 1680x1050 to 2560x1080. In `nvidia-settings` the maximum resolution I can set is only 1920x1080, leaving a substantial gap on each side of the monitor. The display looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRTBy.jpg).

**Attempted solutions:**

I first tried the command `xrandr --fb 2560x1080` but it made absolutely no difference.

I then tried adding support for this resolution the following way:

```
cvt 2560 1080
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-2 2560x1080_60.00
```

The last command returns the error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  32
```

I have no idea how to interpret these error codes and nothing useful is showing up on Google.

**Further details:**

If I boot Windows 7, it detects the monitor's correct resolution and everything works just fine. The monitor's input is HDMI and is connected to a DVI-D dual converter since my 9800 GT graphics card does not support HDMI. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 with NVIDIA binary driver version 340.76.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the only way to fix this problem was to upgrade the graphics card. The new card doesn't have to be anything fancy, a GTX 460 worked for me. Nothing else needed to be done after the new card was installed, no driver updates, no xrandr, etc.